# Number of nine letter words with letters $X$,$Y$ and $Z$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, binomial-coefficients

Find Number of nine letter words with letters $X$,$Y$ and $Z$ such that first three positions should not have any $X$, second three positions cannot be $Y$ and last three positions cannot be $Z$.

For example the word $XYYZZXXYZ$ is not a valid word .

My Try:

one possibility is $YYYZZZXXX$ that is first 3 letters are same. Next three are same and last three are same. This is equivalent to placing 3 letters in 3 envelopes such that no envelope goes to its corresponding envelope which can be done in 2 ways.

any clue for other arrangements?

Comment: Answers so far have assumed (as I would have) that you can use different numbers of each letter. Perhaps you could clarify if this is what you intended or if you meant there to be $3$ $X$s, $3$ $Y$'s and 3 $Z$s. The problem is solvable in either case.

Answer (score 1):

The first three letters must not contain $X$. Hence it contains only $Y's$ and $Z's$. Let there be $(i)$ $Y's$ in first three letters
 Hence we get $(3-i)$ $Z's$ in first three letters.

Using similar argument we get $(i)$ $Z's$ and $(3-i)$ $X's$ in next three letters and $(i)$ $X's$ and $(3-i)$ $Y's$ in last three letters.

So Now for the first three letters we get  the number of arrangements as 
$$\sum_{i=0}^3 \binom{3}{i}$$
The same goes for the next three letters as well as the last three last letters. Hence the total number arrangements we get is

$$\left(\sum_{i=0}^3 \binom{3}{i}\right)^3=512$$

As simple as that:-)

Note: 
A similar question was also asked I guess in AIME or ASHME but I don't remember the year correctly.  I had solved it correctly so seeing this question past memories were brought back. You may search internet for some other Great solutions to such questions in the reference to the question asked in that exam.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, the first three letters can each be either Y or Z, independently, the next three can each be X or Z, and the last three can be X or Y. So, since each letter has two possible values, the answer is simply 2^9 = 512. That almost seems too easy though.

Comment: Yes, perhaps the OP wanted three of each letter, which makes the problem much more interesting.

Comment: Yes i for got to mention that. There we have to use only three of each alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is straightforward and simple. Don't confuse it with derangement problem. As only X,Y,Z are allowed and the only conditions are that X should not be in the first three places, Y should not be in second three places and Z should not be third three places. This leaves each position to have only 2 options. This make the answer to be 2^9 = 512 ways.